# Connecting to my own golang sever from outside world

Tags: http, go

So I do have this code written in `go`:

```
// firstserver - my first server
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Handler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

// Handler - a handler function for a normal enter
func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "You're connected")
}
```

Now, when I go to my browser and type `localhost:80` (or just `localhost`), the page loads, and I see the message `You're connected`. Now I wanted to try to connect from other devices too. So I took my other laptop. I checked my adapter address, its `192.168.0.15`. So when I typed `192.168.0.15:80` on the other laptop, it worked again, cool!

Primarly I am trying to do some simple server to use it on my phone when I am at college, check the schedules, have some notes, etc. I took my smartphone, I disconnected from my WiFi, switched to my smartphones internet and dumbly typed `192.168.0.15:80` again. I knew it wouldn't work, cuz it's not my external IP. And it didn't.

So I looked up the IP address that my ISP provider gives me, it looks like this: `88.156.xxx.xx`. Now on my phone I typed `88.156.xxx.xx:80` and it didn't work. I tried to search SO and other resources on the web on how to connect remotely to my server from outside of LAN. And I didn't find an answer. Is there a way to do that without, I don't know, paying for sorts of things, or something like this?

P.S I'm living in a rented room, there's not only me in the house, so I don't have a way to configure a router (manually or over the web)

Comment: While this may seem off scope, but I suggest you read this guide. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/ the procedure for exposing your go server is near identical as you'll need to open a port on your network and forward it. Dont use port 80 either.

Comment: Forgot to add, that I cannot actually configure the router, cuz I don't have access to it. Only got WiFi password :(

Comment: @Frynio then you're out of luck.

Comment: @Frynio you need access to the router to open the port otherwise it wont work.. Otherwise you might want to try the free tier on heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-go or other like services

Comment: Ah, poor me. Anyway thanks for all your advices guys! Maybe someday I will be given access to the router

Comment: This really isn't a Go- or even programming-related question. This question would be better on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is deploy it on an AWS Free Tier instance with public IP(https://aws.amazon.com/free/). 
Once you are done spinning up the EC2 instance (https://aws.amazon.com/free/), copy the binary of your web server to that instance `scp -i mykey.pem somefile.txt root@my.ec2.id.amazonaws.com:/`

You need to ensure that the security group on that instance allows ingress from the internet(0.0.0.0/0) on that port

To access it:
Use either the public IP or public DNS of the EC2 instance along with the port number of your server(in your case 80)